# Is there any limit when using django filtter "__in"?

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

It case some problem when using "__in" grammar  ,it should be 100 records but finnal return less than 100

```py
class Teacher(model.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
```

```
class Student(model.Model):
    teacher =  models.ForeignKey(Teacher,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this are models,but it was not the problem I have meet,that case was more complicated than it, I try to show the key point;

I try to recurrence the problem, it looks like:

I want to get all students that their teacher's id in [1,2,3,4]

so I try to use :

```py
   teachers =  Teacher.objects.filter(in__in=[1,2,3,4])
   students = Student.objcets.filter(teacher_id__in=teachers)
```

and it catch some problem, the data is not complete,it less than expect

as we know,it is better to use:

```py
   teachers_list =  Teacher.objects.filter(in__in=[1,2,3,4]).values("id",flat=True)
   students = Student.objcets.filter(teacher_id__in=list(teacher_list))
```

It exactly cause the problem when i use the first sentence; but i can't recurrence it any more,So i want to know whether it will raise problem 
when using "__in = queryset" instead of "in__in = list"

sorry my English is very poor, and I have done my best to describe the problem,Expect your answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It case some problem when using `__in` grammar ,it should be 100 records but final return less than 100

You used <s>`id__in`</s>, instead of `teacher__in`. Nevertheless, it is *not* a good idea to filter like that, you can use two consecutive underscores (`__`) to look "through" a relation, like:

```
students = Student.objects.filter(teacher__id__in=[1,2,3,4])
```

or even simpler:

```
students = Student.objects.filter(teacher_id__in=[1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: thank you, but i want to know whether it will cause problem when using "id__in" = a queryset

Comment: @Steve: by using `id__in`, as said in the question, you retrieve `Student`s who's **`id`** is in the list of `ids` in the `teachers` queryset. But the `id` of a student has nothing to do with the id of a teacher (in fact it is a non-sensical query). Furthermore the query `Teacher.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4]).values('id')` is non-sensical as well, since that will return... the ids of the ids you just queried for, so `[1,2,3,4]` (unless no teacher can be found with that id).

Comment: @Steve: as for limitations on `__in`, most databases have length limits on the query, so it might be possible that an `__in` fails, if the list is huge. Then you will usually get an error, not a subset of the objects to retrieve.

Comment: oh,thans a lot,Thanks a million, you are so nice , it was a very big data when i meet that problem